# how to improve the performance of smartgwt listgrid

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, listgrid

I have to show around 30,000 records.I am using the `datasource.setdata()` to set the records. My listgrid fetch the records from the attached datasource. But I am facing a performance issue. it takes too much time to show the records and if i update the records then my browser(IE & firefox) both get hangs.
What is the possible solution of this problem??

These records are at client side only. I have to do some operation on the records then i have to save.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as DataSource.setData()..

The best way to do this is to implement paging so that you do not load all 30,000 records into the browser.  This will improve server performance as well since the server will not have to deliver such a large dataset when most users will only look at a handful of records.  To see how to do all this, look at the SmartGWT QuickStart Guide and focus on the Data Binding and Data Integration chapters.

If for some reason you have to load 30,000 records you had better encourage your users not to use IE.  Then, use a client-only DataSource.

As far as some kind of "hang when updating" you need to be more specific.

Comment: Bill Ellwood:I have search about the paging concept but not able to find the paging component.Can u plz tell me how the pagination can be apply into the listgrid.i found follwing link regarding the pagination but don,t know hoe to use at client side only      
                                   http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/DataSource.html#transformRequest(com.smartgwt.client.data.DSRequest)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Paging` component in `Smartgwt`, you have to implement it yourself. 
I had the same problem as yours.

The solution was simulating `Paging`:
The client doesn't retrieve the **30,000 records**, instead he asks for the first **100 records**. When the user scrolls to the the bottom of the `listGrid` (there is an event for scroll), the client asks the server for the next **100 records**, etc ..

Comment: @Adel Boutros: I followed many links but i got only theory.If you any sample code then please share it.

Comment: @Dhruva Sorry man, I haven't implemented my solution neither. Actually you can try to imitate the pagging which is available in GWT: http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid

Comment: @AdelBoutros: i am using smartGWT listgrid,so that not able to use  datagrid paging functionality.Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Dhruva I did not say "use", i said "imitate".

Comment: @AdelBoutros:finally i have implemented it myself thanks to all.